# Excel VBA is it possible to allow sorting on locked cells?

Tags: vba, excel

**At first I had:**

```
ws.Protect Password:="x", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

This allowed me to filter ok, but when I tried to sort ascending, nothing happened

**SO then** I put in the `AllowSorting:=True`:

```
ws.Protect Password:="x", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
    AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

Now when I try and sort ascending - it just tells me my worksheet is protected...

I figure this is because my cells are locked so -

**is there not a way to allow sorting of locked cells?!**

Comment: Thats correct, if you have any locked cells in the filtered region you cannot sort by any column.

Comment: No way round it? Bit annoying that I can filter but not sort :( will have to create a custom way to do this

Comment: Filtering just hides or displays rows, sorting has to rearrange data, and what would be the point of locking cells if you can still manipulate it.

Comment: Well the point would be to rearrange it without changing the cell contents... Don't tell me you can't see that...

Comment: I can even flip the question and ask what's the point of being able to protect a sheet with the allow reordering option - if the cells aren't locked to allow reordering then why bother protecting it in the first place? There's a point to everything depending on a need and I need to lock the table contents while allowing it to be reordered.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how sorting works, it works by changing the cell contents. The only way around it would be to unlock the data first, sort it, then lock the sheet again.

Comment: Of course I understand it, it's moving contents from row 1 to row 2 e.g. cell A1 is now different - but I figured the "Protect while AllowSorting" option implied Excel had an in-built workaround to allow cell changes if applied by sorting... there's no need to pretend it's a ridiculous notion to save face.

Comment: I'm just trying to help, it can't be done how you want, and accepting that locking cells protects those cells, is the first step to understanding why it can't be done.